# document.getElementById("myFile").value gets undefined using electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I have a very basic html file (using electron);

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> File Uploader </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="render.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>Drive File Uploader</h1>
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile">
    <button onclick="FileUploadPing()">Upload your file</button>

</body>
</html>
```

and an event listener named render.js;

```
const ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer;

const FileUploadPing = () => {
  var input = document.getElementById("myFile").value
  if (input) {
    ipcRenderer.send("FileUploadPing",inputVal);
  }else{console.log("no path value")}
};

ipcRenderer.on("FileRecievePing", (event, data) => {
  alert(data)
});
```

But when I click submit, `document.getElementById("myFile").value` returns `undefined`

how can I pull that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting issue that confronts many people using Electron. One could either use (via Electron) the native OS [dialog.showOpenDialog([browserWindow, ]options)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options) dialog or the html [<input type="file">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) tag.

To circumvent the need to manage the [is prefixed with C:\fakepath\](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#fakepath-srsly) issue, it is often better to use the native approach. After all, that is what Electron is best at.

Let me show you how to quickly set up a html button that when clicked, will open the native file selector dialog, and when a path is selected, return the path to the render thread for display.

In the below code, we will be using a `preload.js` script configured to communicate ([using IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc)) between the main thread and render thread(s). [Context Isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation) will describe this in more detail.

First off, let's code the `main.js` file which will include the creation of the native file dialog.

`main.js` (main thread)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronDialog = require('electron').dialog;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const nodePath = require("path");

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 1000,
        height: 700,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); })

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// Open the file dialog
electronIpcMain.on('message:openDialog', (event) => {
    let options = {
        title: 'Select File',
        properties: ['openFile']
    };

    electronDialog.showOpenDialog(window, options)
        .then((result) => {
            if (result.canceled) {
                console.log('User cancelled file dialog.');
                return;
            }

            event.reply('message:dialogPath', result.filePaths[0]);
        })
        .catch((error) => { console.error(error); });
})
```

---

Now, let's create the `index.html` file, which for the sake of simplicity, also includes the Javascript within the `<script>` tags.

> NB: Instead of deferring your script in the `<head>`, you can include it just before the closing `<html>` tag. Placing it here effectively performs the same thing as `defer` in the `<head>` `<script>` tag.

`index.html` (render thread)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Drive File Uploader</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>Drive File Uploader</div>
        <hr>

        <label for="path">Path: </label>
        <input type="text" id="path" name="path">
        <input type="button" id="open-dialog" name="open-dialog" value="...">

        <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload">
    </body>

    <script>
        // Let's declare it as it is used more than once
        let filePath = document.getElementById('path');

        // Event listeners
        document.getElementById('open-dialog').addEventListener('click', () => { window.ipcRender.send('message:openDialog'); });
        document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('click', () => { console.log(filePath.value); });

        // IPC message from the main thread
        window.ipcRender.receive('message:dialogPath', (path) => { filePath.value = path; })
    </script>
</html>
```

---

Finally, let's add the `preload.js` script to allow the main thread and render thread(s) to safely communicate with each other.

> Note: This is where we define our [whitelisted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelisting) channel names.

`preload.js` (main thread)

```js
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [
            'message:openDialog'
        ],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [
            'message:dialogPath'
        ],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': []
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Hopefully, the above outlines how simple it can be to use (via Electron) the native dialog boxes. The benefit being they have OS specific functionality and feel.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what I did different, but when I tried this it suddenly worked.

main.js;

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require("electron");

let win = null;

const createWindow = () => {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    resizable: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      nativeWindowOpen: true,
    },
  });

  win.loadFile("index.html");
};

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);
```

render.js;

```
const ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer;
const {uploadFileToCloud} = require("C:/Users/efeba/desktop/pythonAndJS/ITGSProject/app.js")

const FileUploadPing = () => {
  var name = document.getElementById("myFile").value
  name = name.replace("C:\\fakepath\\","")
  console.log(name)
  var path = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0].path
  path = path.replace(name,"")
  path = path.replaceAll("\\", "/") // beautify the string
  console.log(path)
  if (path) {
    uploadFileToCloud(name, path)
    alert("File Uploaded")
  }else{console.log("no path value")}
};

//file uploads but content is empty
//I suspect pulling the libraries in renderer has some problems, will
//try to make it by sending a ping to main.js
```

index.html;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> File Uploader </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="render.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>Drive File Uploader</h1>
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile">
    <button onclick="FileUploadPing()">Upload your file</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope I could help